# How do I get all the strings in double quotes into an array?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, split, preg-match

I have a string like:- `Array ( [jsonarray]=>["BRMS01","BRMS02","BRMS03"])1`.

How can I parse it in such a way that I get only the strings inside double quotes, like `BRMS01`.

This is the code I have tried so far

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$jsonArray=json_decode($_POST['jsonArray']);
preg_match_all('/".*?"|\'.*?\'/', $jsonArray, $matches);

exit(print_r($matches));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But I get an empty array. Any help is appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you @jarlh can you help with a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know php.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$_POST['jsonArray'] = '["BRMS01","BRMS02","BRMS03"]';
$jsonArray=json_decode($_POST['jsonArray']);
print_r($jsonArray);exit;
```

The result would be:

```js
Array
(
    [0] => BRMS01
    [1] => BRMS02
    [2] => BRMS03
)
```

you can use $jsonArray[0] get waht you need

Comment: Even after I decode it the response i get is Array([jsonarray]=>["BRMS01","BRMS05","BRMS04"])1.Because when i send the data from my volley code i send the array as a string.So I send a single string. How to parse this can you help?

Comment: in your code line 4, use var_dump($jsonArray);exit; What can you get?

Comment: I got null as a response

Comment: and  var_dump($_POST['jsonArray']) ??

Comment: Again I got a NULL what do you think is the problem?

Comment: and var_dump($_POST) ? you need set form method='post' (see:http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php)

Comment: Yes I am using Post.This time the response is "array(1) { ["jsonarray"]=>string(10)"["BRMS01"]"}"

Comment: then,try:$jsonArray=json_decode($_POST['jsonarray']);print_r($jsonArray);exit;